# Get the src value of img by referencing to an CSS parameter in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have my images all listed in this format, upon clicking `NEXT` button via jquery it will loop through the images. Appending `inline` value to `display:` parameter of the current selected image. the rest of the image will display `none`.

```
<div class="images" style="display: block;">
<img src="http://somepic1.png" width="20" id="1" style="display: none;">
<img src="http://somepic2.png" width="20" id="2" style="display: inline;">
<img src="http://somepic3.png" width="20" id="3" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

now i want to get the `src` value of the current selected image that contains the value of `inline` in its display parameter.

ive tried below code, but this only prints the first image src "somepic1.png", even though the current selected image is the second `<img>`.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.submit', function () {
    var img = $('img').prop('src');
    alert(img);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

`:visible` means visible element on DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.submit', function () {
       var img = $(".images").find("img:visible").prop("src");
       alert(img);
    });
});
```

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HmjYv/)